# After Effects: Expression reading specific Audio-frequency

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to get a result similar to that of the audio_spectrum effect, but want to build it from scratch since the settings of the effect are quite lackluster.

Here's the plan:

- create a square
- create keyframes from audio amplitude
- attach amplitude from audio to scaling of the square, making it grow in y-size only.

So far so good, I have all this working. But now, I want to read a different frequency depending on the x-position of my square, so that if I shift it over to one end of the audio-spectrum, it automatically adapts to the corresponding frequency. My very last resort would be to output the audio with low- and highpass already on them, but that would be highly unpractical.

If you kind people know what I am missing please let me know. Have a wonderful day :)